# How to how multiple label chips in multiple dynamic collectionview cells with image or without image in swift 5?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I want to show multiple set of string data in multiple dynamic collection view cells in swift

Example image attaches:

[image: first collection view cell with labels]

[image: 2nd slide of cell with label data]

[image: 3rd slide of collection view]

How I can achieve this in dynamic collection view to show one cell at a time and other on scroll like slider.

Comment: It is difficult to do with collection view. Collection view has some restrictions. It is better to go through normal views. Through programatically it is comfortable.

Comment: @phani but how... I'm stuck there from last 20 days

Comment: guide me ..how I can achieve this...:)

Comment: First add a scroll view. Next add UIView (like cell). In cell add UIView for header part and remaining part you need add labels. For width of UILabels you need to calculate dynamically.

Comment: @phani how to show multiple dynamic labels?

Comment: It's not a simple code to share. drop your personal mail. Sunday I will send the code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204167/discussion-between-phani-and-balu-sama).